# How do I change the prepackaged music to custom ones of my own?

Tags: terraria

Listening to the same old songs is getting kind of bland. So to fix that I want to know how to get rid of the prepackaged songs (sorry Scott Shelly) and replace them with some files of my own. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Isn't that what steam music is for?

Comment: Is it possible to do that with Steam Music? I thought it was just a substitute media player if you were too lazy to download VLC. Anyways, I'm looking for a non-Steam Music approach to this.

Comment: Mute in game music volume , and play your playlist using music player.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to replace the in-game soundtrack with songs of your choosing. The game will even handle transitioning from one song to the next depending on what biome you're in/which enemies you're facing/etc. However, although the process only requires replacing the soundtrack file, creating the new soundtrack file in the first place is a pretty big hassle.

The detailed steps are listed on [this page](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/custom-wave-bank-creation-and-installation-1-3-4-x-beyond.51635/), but I will summarize the steps here:

1. Download and install Visual Studio (yes, the programming tool).
2. Download and install XNA Game Studio.
3. Download and install an audio editor. (Audacity is recommended in the linked guide)
4. Take all the songs you want and export them into WAV format.
5. Open the Microsoft Cross-Platform Audio Creation Tool (XACT) - should be included in the XNA Game Studio installation.
6. Use XACT to create a wavebank file. Detailed instruction in the linked guide. (Or you can probably find other tutorials online.) *Make sure to add the music files exactly like the guide explains, or the wavebank will not work.*
7. Take the wavebank file (Wave Bank.xwb) and move it to Steam\SteamApps\common\Terraria\Content. (Make sure to back up the old file in case you need to switch back.)

Once done, you should be able to start the game as usual and your custom soundtrack will play.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn the music volume down to zero, then use your regular music player. Adjust the volume in your music player until it's at the right level, relative to the game sounds.

Comment: Although this solution allows you to control the music while playing, being able to actually replace the game music allows you to do what the game does, which is to play different selections based on Terraria day/night, weather, biome you are in, or boss you are fighting. Your solution lacks the ability to play context related music.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to replace the preexisting music with some of your own without mods. However, there are related things that might help:

-You can change the music to a different in-game song using [Music Boxes](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Music_Boxes)

-You can mute the in-game music through the options and play your own music

-In the future, I've heard that the last update, 1.4, will add creative mode -- this might add the ability to play your own songs, or maybe if it comes with some sort of command system you could do it that way. No guarantee.